# Laravel Collection - Returning a total with sum() on nested arrays

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**I am trying to return a total using sum() by fetching the "duration" from each user within a $collection**

The structure is

USER > CONTRACT_RESULTS > DAYS > DATE > ACTIVITIES > ACTIVITY

I want to query the "type" of activity and pull back the duration that is associated with that activity.

I had it working when it was much less nested using:

```
$collection->whereIn('activity',['off'])->sum('duration');
```

But I'm at a loss now since they are so nested and the names of the arrays are dynamic

**Here is an example of the structure for 1 user in the $collection:**

```
array:13 [▼
  "user_id" => 52
   "contract_results" => array:2 [▼
    "2019-10-21 - 2019-10-31" => array:10 [▼
      "hours_a_week" => "20"
      "days" => array:1 [▼
        "2019-10-21" => array:2 [▼
          "bank_holiday" => "no"
          "activities" => array:2 [▼
            "10:00 - 22:00" => array:5 [▼
              "type" => "driving"
              "from" => "10:00"
              "to" => "22:00"
              "duration" => 720
              "night_minutes" => 60
            ]
            "22:00 - 00:00" => array:5 [▼
              "type" => "driving"
              "from" => "22:00"
              "to" => "00:00"
              "duration" => 120
              "night_minutes" => 120
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "2019-11-01 - 2019-11-10" => array:10 [▼
      "hours_a_week" => "10"
      "days" => array:1 [▼
        "2019-11-01" => array:2 [▼
          "bank_holiday" => "yes"
          "activities" => array:1 [▼
            "10:00 - 22:00" => array:5 [▼
              "type" => "availability"
              "from" => "10:00"
              "to" => "22:00"
              "duration" => 720
              "night_minutes" => 60
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm new to this so, thank you very much for your input!

Comment: What is `activity`? I don't see `activity` in your collection.

Comment: activity is arrays with the name set as times under the "activities" array - an example is "10:00 - 22:00" within each is type, from, to, duration, night minutes

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Look at your `->whereIn('activity', ['off'])`. I don't see `activity` key in your collection.

Comment: Before I had a much simpler array and there was an array called "activity" now I have a more complex nested array and there is an array called "activities" and within this lots of arrays with dynamic names like "10:00 - 22:00" these are now the new "activity" that I need to query..

if it was a loop it would be like:
$duration_total = '';
for each "days" as day - for each activities as activity $duration_total .= duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `unclear` information, this is all that I can do:

```php
$durationTotal = collect($data->get('contract_results'))
        ->transform(function ($contractResult) {
            return array_merge((array) $contractResult, [
                'days' => collect(data_get($contractResult, 'days'))
                    ->transform(function ($day) {
                        return array_merge((array) $day, [
                            'activities' => collect(data_get($day, 'activities'))
                                ->whereIn('type', ['driving'])
                                ->toArray()
                        ]);
                    })
                    ->toArray()
            ]);
        })
        ->sum(function ($item) {
            return array_sum(data_get($item, 'days.*.activities.*.duration', []));
        });
```

Comment: Just had chance to try it and it worked a charm - thank you so much - sorry for being unclear

Comment: Glad if it works. Feel free to ask if you'd another problem. Feel free to upvote too 